# Reset password custom validation issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6, laravel-7

I'm using laravel 7

And In my password reset I have following form code,

reset.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.E-Mail Address') }}*</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"  autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('sentence.Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation"  autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default subscribe px-5">
                                    {{ __('sentence.Reset Password') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And i have default ResetPasswordController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

THE PROBLEM

Now my issue is, I need to change the password validation rules according to my need. But I  can't find where to make the changes, I'm trying change the min character limit and add a regex.

Reset process working properly except I'm failing to add my validation rules..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite the function `rules` within your controller, as it's being defined in the trait `ResetsPasswords`:

```
use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function rules()
{
  // return your custom rules here
}
```